# Spotify Get User's Saved Tracks 500 error (Python)

Tags: python, spotify, http-status-code-500

I received my `OAuth token` with the following scopes:

> user-library-read
> playlist-read-private
> playlist-read-collaborative
> playlist-modify-private
> playlist-modify-public

All of my api calls work except for the `Get User's Saved Tracks` which returns a `500`. I tried multiple calls over 30 minutes with no change in response. Below is my code, could anyone confirm if it truly if I have anything to fix in my code or it truly is on Spotify's end?

```
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(oauth_token),
    }
     
    params = (
        ('market', 'US'),
        ('limit', '50'),
        ('offset', '0')
    )
    
    
    int_response = 429
    while int_response == 429:
        response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks', headers=headers, params=params)
        print('get response: ', response)
        int_response = response.status_code
        if int_response == 429:
            print('Retry-After: {0}'.format(response.headers['Retry-After']))
            print('ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ')
            time.sleep(int(response.headers['Retry-After'])+1)
    
    json_response = json.loads(response.content)
        
    try:
        json_items = json_response['items']
    except:
        print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=3, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: I cannot find an obvious error in your code. As you may know, HTTP 500 means the server is having errors. I suggest retrying at a later time (several hours later).